# override log4j configuration with another log4j.xml file

Tags: java, log4j

Is it possible to add or override log4j configuration previously loaded by log4j.xml file with another log4j.xml file loaded at runtime ?

My Glassfish server loads at startup log4j.xml file and I would like to change this configuration with another log4j.xml file in EAR file.

I tried to use `DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml")` but it seems that the previously configuration is not overrided (but this method find log4j.xml file because when I change to non existing file, I have Exception).

How can I do this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A log4j `Configurator` always applies its configuration starting from the "current" settings.  If you want the new settings to replace the old ones, simply call `LogManager.resetConfiguration()` first, before calling the `DOMConfigurator`.

Comment: I tested it before but for my case, it doesn't work. Context is : log4j.xml loaded at Glassfish startup and I want this file to be overrided by another log4j.xml file in EAR project. I test this inside servlet which is loaded at startup (<load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>)

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem. DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch("log4j.xml"); loads the log4j.xml file in Glassfish (the one already loaded...) not the new in my EAR, I don't know why